# Change Display Name of Description Field

Tags: acumatica

I want to change the display name of PXSelector Description Field for a specific page. I try as below but it is not working:

```cs
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName(sender, "DistributorID_description", "ABC-XYZ");
```

Comment: In what event did you try? Give more details

Comment: Could you please be more specific with your request and provide Screen ID and selector caption you want to customize?

To improve chances of receiving an answer, please take a look at stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Hybridzz: I used it in RowSelected Events

Comment: @RuslanDev: I'm sorry, because my english is not good so I difficult to explain my problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

try using the initialize() instead of row selected to set the same using the below syntax

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<DACName.fieldName>(CacheRelatedToYourDAC, "newValue");
```

OR

you can use the CacheAttached Event to change the displayname of your field. *Dont forget to copy all your existing attributes here*

```
[DAC_Field_Attribute_1]
...
[DAC_Field_Attribute_N]
protected virtual void DACName_FieldName_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
    ...
}
```